# how to insert a fullname column into name and last name columns MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, split, sql-insert

Have a table named `school_teachers` which have a `full_name` column,
And another table named `teachers` which have `name` and `last_name` columns.

I'm inserting the `school_teachers` data into the `teachers` table,

So how should I insert that full name column into name and last name columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following query.

```
INSERT INTO teachers (`name`, `last_name`)
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1),
        ' ',
        - 1
    ) AS `name`,
    IF(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 1) = full_name,
        "",
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(full_name, ' ', 2),
            ' ',
            - 1
        )
    ) AS last_name
FROM
    `school_teachers` ;
```

Comment: Sorry, MySQL doesn't have that kind of builtin function. This is my best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You would concatenate them.  I would recommend using `concat_ws()` because it handles `NULL` values more elegantly than `concat()`.  So:

```
insert into school_teachers ( . . ., full_name)
     select . . ., concat_ws(name, last_name)
     from teachers t;
```

That said, you should probably only be putting the id into a table with essentially two columns, the `school_id` and the `teacher_id`.  There is no need to copy all the other columns.  That is a bad use of databases -- you can use `JOIN` to get a teacher's name when you need it.

Comment: aw, I meant to insert the school teachers into the teachers